# use directives in angular to add HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this HTML code (protocol-modal.html) which I want to add to my main HTML file as a directive:

```
<div class="modal-content">

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="questionForm">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{ tctrl.currentDataObject.title }}</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    ng-model="tctrl.formData.name" id="name"
                    placeholder="{{ tctrl.currentDataObject.placeholder }}"/>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- This button calls the method that performs the POST request-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="tctrl.processForm()">Add</button>

        <hr></hr>

        <!--TABLE STARTS HERE-->

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>

              <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="c in tctrl.currentDataObject.tableColumns"> {{ c }} </th>
              </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>

               <!-- Loop through tctrl.protocolList-->
              <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in tctrl.protocolList">

                <!--Access the actual values inside each of the objects in the array-->
                    <td ng-repeat="v in value" > {{ v }} </td>

                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Edit {{ tctrl.currentDataObject.tr }}</button>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="tctrl.remove(value)">Remove</button>
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            <div class="pull-left">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                    data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

under my controller in js-file, I add the following:

```
.directive('protocolModal', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'protocol-modal.html'
    };
});
```

And in my main HTML file, I try to use it like so:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addEntry" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->

                <protocol-modal></protocol-modal>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The error I receive in the console looks like this:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

here is what my folder structure looks like:

[image]

Comment: protocol-modal.html - 404 not found - check the location.

Comment: From which page do you try to find `protocol-modal.html`?

Comment: @Mikey index.html and the directive is in custom.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right there in your console.  You must have the wrong URL for `protocol-modal.html`, because Angular is hitting a 404 when trying to load it.

Comment: I updated my question with what my folder structure looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong path to your template

> templateUrl: 'protocol-modal.html'

Because of that file template file cannot be found.

Change it to proper path should help.

UPDATE:
If project is on root in your server it should look like:

> /templates/protocol-modal.html

You can too do something like this:

> http://localhost:8080/templates/protocol-modal.html

It depends on witch way you host your project

Comment: I updated my question with what my folder structure looks like. What would be the correct URL based on this?

Comment: hmm - I tried both ways and I still get the same errror : /

Comment: try resources/templates/protocol-modal.html 
i'm not familiar with java routing

Comment: still same error : / . I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm missing in the url